# Bash loop involving variables not working

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write this simple script which converts a bunch of .png images into an animated gif using ImageMagick. My files are called firstNeighboursDistribution_strength_XXXbosons_13window_YYY.png where XXX={0.0 0.001 0.0025 0.005 0.05 0.1 0.15} and YYY={1,3,5...}. The following code won't show any message on console, it seems it's stuck. What's wrong with it?

```
#$ -S /bin/bash 
LANG=C #Enforce English. Crucial to get decimal *points* (rather than commas)

for f in 0.0 0.001 0.0025 0.005 0.05 0.1 0.15;
do
convert -delay 400 -dispose Background +page firstNeighboursDistribution_strength_$fbosons_13window_*.png -loop 0 Animation_first_neigh_strength_$f.gif;
done
```

Pleas note the following code does work as expected:

```
convert -delay 400 -dispose Background +page firstNeighboursDistribution_strength_XXXbosons_13window_*.png -loop 0 Animation_first_neigh_strength_$f.gif;
```

for any suitable vale of XXX.

Comment: If you want to enforce English, LANG=en or LANG=en_GB, to be excruciatingly precise.  "LANG=C" is not English.  It is ASCII.

Comment: You are right Bruce K, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put curly braces around your variable name. Bash doesn't try to match variables, if it finds a `$` followed by a valid variable name, it will simply use that. So, in your code, Bash assumes that this is the variable name:

```
$fbosons_13window_
```

This is because each of the characters between the `$` and the `*` are valid variable name characters. To fix this, you'll need to surround your variable name with `{` and `}` to tell bash the exact variable name, like this:

```
${f}bosons_13window_
```

The full line of code in the loop would be this:

```
convert -delay 400 -dispose Background +page firstNeighboursDistribution_strength_${f}bosons_13window_*.png -loop 0 Animation_first_neigh_strength_$f.gif;
```

As a sidenote, this is recommended for ANY variable that you use as part of a string. Curly braces can resolve a lot of subtle bugs in bash scripts.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `$fSomething` expands the variable `fSomething`; *not* `f` and concatenates `Something`.

Use braces `{}` around your variable `f`:

```
convert -delay 400 -dispose Background +page firstNeighboursDistribution_strength_${f}bosons_13window_*.png -loop 0 Animation_first_neigh_strength_${f}.gif;
```

Answer (score 1):

your f variable should be like `${f}bosnos`